# deploy a contract,this contract need to be the another contract owner

Tags: solidity

```
contract MoonToken is IMoonToken {
    uint256 private constant MAX_UINT256 = type(uint256).max;
    mapping(address => uint256) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint256)) public allowed;

    string public constant name = "MOON Token";
    string public constant symbol = "MOON";
    uint8 public constant decimals = 18;

    uint256 public totalSupply;
    address public owner;

    constructor() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner == msg.sender, "You are not the owner");
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address _newOwner) external onlyOwner {
        owner = _newOwner;
    }

    function transfer(
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) external returns (bool success) {
        require(balances[msg.sender] >= _value);
        balances[msg.sender] -= _value;
        balances[_to] += _value;
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(
        address _from,
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    ) external returns (bool success) {
        uint256 allowance_ = allowed[_from][msg.sender];
        require(balances[_from] >= _value && allowance_ >= _value);

        balances[_to] += _value;
        balances[_from] -= _value;

        if (allowance_ < MAX_UINT256) {
            allowed[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        }
        return true;
    }

    function balanceOf(address _owner) external view returns (uint256 balance) {
        return balances[_owner];
    }

    function approve(
        address _spender,
        uint256 _value
    ) external returns (bool success) {
        allowed[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        return true;
    }

    function allowance(
        address _owner,
        address _spender
    ) external view returns (uint256 remaining) {
        return allowed[_owner][_spender];
    }

    function mint(
        address _to,
        uint256 _value
    )
        external
        onlyOwner // MoonVault must be the contract owner
        returns (bool success)
    {
        balances[_to] += _value;
        totalSupply += _value;
        return true;
    }

    function burnAccount(
        address _from
    )
        external
        onlyOwner // MoonVault must be the contract owner
        returns (bool success)
    {
        uint256 amountToBurn = balances[_from];
        balances[_from] -= amountToBurn;
        totalSupply -= amountToBurn;
        return true;
    }
}

// InsecureMoonVault must be the contract owner of the MoonToken
contract InsecureMoonVault is ReentrancyGuard {
    IMoonToken public immutable moonToken;

    constructor(IMoonToken _moonToken) {
        moonToken = _moonToken;
    }

    function deposit() external payable noReentrant {
        // Apply the noReentrant modifier
        bool success = moonToken.mint(msg.sender, msg.value);
        require(success, "Failed to mint token");
    }

    function withdrawAll() external noReentrant {
        // Apply the noReentrant modifier
        uint256 balance = getUserBalance(msg.sender);
        require(balance > 0, "Insufficient balance");

        (bool success, ) = msg.sender.call{value: balance}("");
        require(success, "Failed to send Ether");

        success = moonToken.burnAccount(msg.sender);
        require(success, "Failed to burn token");
    }

    function getBalance() external view returns (uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }

    function getUserBalance(address _user) public view returns (uint256) {
        return moonToken.balanceOf(_user);
    }
}
```

this is my code, how to deploy contracts(MoonToken and InsecureMoonVault),which can satisfitied condition (InsecureMoonVault must be the contract owner of the MoonToken).use foundry or hardhat